# EDB Postgres Distributed (PGD) node restart do not replicates data

Tags: postgresql, replication, enterprisedb

I have followed instruction from [PDG Docker](https://www.enterprisedb.com/docs/pgd/latest/quickstart/quick_start_docker/)
and installed everything as described, and everything went well.

After creating the schema in the BDRDB database, I ensured that it was successfully replicated to other nodes.

Next, I deliberately stopped one node by turning down the corresponding Docker container. During this time, I inserted a few records on the remaining active node. Subsequently, I restarted the Docker container. However, contrary to my expectations, the previously inserted records did not replicate.

Then, when I insert new records on any of the nodes, they are properly replicated. However, the records that were inserted while the Docker container was offline still haven't been replicated to that specific Docker image.

When I check BDR tables I see the following:

[node_replication_rates](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eFsgx.png)

[node_slots](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Qn1UX.png)

It appears that the replicated data exists in the system, but the replication itself is not currently active?